# A word for the phenomenon of "right result with wrong reasoning"

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

Is there a word that describes the phenomenon or process that someone comes to a right conclusion through wrong reasoning? Thank you!

I'm writing an essay about a novel, in which the husband suspects that the wife has an affair. His evidence is wrong, but the wife is indeed having an affair, and I'm trying to come up with a word that describes this situation, if possible.

After some searching, I found no word that satisfies the meaning, and that's why I'm asking for your help. Thanks for @Tuffy's comment, but I guess that's a rather philosophical concern, i.e., the Gettier problem.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNLa6.png

Comment: First, Yulia, part of the Stack Exchange approach is that the questioner should show how she had researched her own question in search for the answer.  Having said that, strictly speaking, no one can come to the right answer THROUGH the wrong reasoning.  If I reason that all dogs have four legs and conclude that because that creature, Rover, that I see, has four legs it must be a dog, I reason wrongly, even though Rover happens, by chance, to be a dog.  In fact, there is a name for this kind of fallacy:  ‘illicit conversion’.  Beware of it in politics and advertising!

Comment: Something like [_ass backwards_](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/ass-backwards), perhaps?

Comment: I'd reason that it's really "coming to the right conclusion **in spite of** wrong reasoning" -- *a fluke,* sort of.

Comment: @Kris Ah yes, "in spite of"! That's the word I should have used... thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I call it [dumb luck](https://www.google.com/search?q=dumb%20luck&num=100&newwindow=1&rlz=1C1PRFI_enUS771US771&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwisyqCzzK7aAhWp5oMKHW8KDfYQ_AUIECgB&biw=1280&bih=590), and apparently so do a lot of other people. It seems to be a very popular title for all kinds of books.

According to Oxford Dictionary online, it means: "[Pure chance](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/dumb_luck)", which logically can't have much if anything to do with reason.

- The husband suspects that the wife has an affair. His evidences are wrong, but the wife is indeed having an affair. So finding out about it is sheer **dumb luck**. Or intuition.

Comment: I was going to say "dumb luck" was the term that immediately came to mind for me, too.

Answer (score 0):

**serendipity**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/serendipity)

> the faculty of making fortunate discoveries **by accident**

synonym of serendipity: a lucky **fluke**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/fluke)

> 1. an accidental stroke of luck
> 2. any chance happening